# How to save the state of Spinner in onSaveInstanceState when changing the orientation in android

Tags: android

I want to save the state (ie. content) of spinner tied to an Adapter when chnaging the orientation. I am using onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) method . 
Will u give the step by step process how to save the content?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent example of how to do this (look at onPause & onResume), [Spinner Example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Spinner/src/com/android/example/spinner/SpinnerActivity.html).  I would strongly suggest also adding activity testing (aka unit testing) to make sure you restore all your states around the lifecycles. [unit test example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/activity_testing.html#RunOnUIThread).

Comment: I could find no Spinner sample in Android API 16+.